# Twain library generate access violation error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, twain

I'm trying to make a program that take a picture directly from the scanner and save it so I found library to help me doing that it's name TWain https://sarafftwain.codeplex.com/
it worked well with .net v2 target framework but when I tried to use it with .net v4 it generates this exception :

```
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
```

so can anyone help me with that. 
(I'm running on Windows 10)

here's the program:

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {

            Twain32 _twain32 = new Twain32();
                _twain32.ShowUI = true;                     
                _twain32.IsTwain2Enable = true ; 

                _twain32.OpenDSM();

                _twain32.AcquireCompleted+=(sender,e) => {

                };

                _twain32.Acquire();
                Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: this is likely to be a problem with the library, check their site for support, also have you tried their WPF example https://sarafftwain.codeplex.com/releases/view/119813

Comment: I tried to run it out of visual studio and it worked fine .

Comment: @RamiZK did you find the fix